# veracrypt misidentifies disk size

Tags: terminal, encryption, veracrypt

I tried creating a hidden partition on a **4TiB disk** with veracrypt and it reports that only **416MiB are available**. How can I create a hidden partition of (almost) the whole disk with the veracrypt cli?

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/disk/by-id/MY-DISK`

```
Disk /dev/disk/by-id/MY-DISK: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
```

`sudo veracrypt -t -c --volume-type=hidden /dev/disk/by-id/MY-DISK --encryption=twofish --hash=whirlpool --filesystem=none -p 'mypassword' --pim=0 -k "" --random-source=/dev/urandom --size=3950G`

```
Error: Incorrect volume size
```

Using the interactive variant `sudo veracrypt -t -c --volume-type=hidden /dev/disk/by-id/MY-DISK --encryption=twofish --hash=whirlpool --filesystem=none -p 'mypassword' --pim=0 -k "" --random-source=/dev/urandom`

```
Enter hidden volume size (sizeK/size[M]/sizeG/sizeT/max): 3950G
Error: Maximum volume size is 416 MiB.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug (See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/1180)) in veracrypt-console which is fixed in 1.26.5.